# ¿A qué se refiere "colgado del balcón de tus ojos" en "Desesperadamente Enamorado" de Jordi?

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Qué es lo que está "colgado" en "colgado del balcón de tus ojos" en la canción "[Desesperadamente Enamorado](https://www.albumcancionyletra.com/desesperadamente-enamorado_de_jordi___180654.aspx)" de Jordi? ¿Y a qué se refiere "el balcón" en la canción? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tampoco creo que haya que ser un entendido en idiomas para comprender que se trata de una metáfora, idioma universal.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo Usted. Para entender una metáfora hay que entender el idioma que se usa en ella. Si no, ¿cómo va a entender el significado de cada palabra en una metáfora?

Comment: En mi caso, entendí todas las palabras, separadas, en la expresión asociada a mi pregunta, pero yo no sabía que "estar colgado por alguien" significa estar profundamente enamorado. Pensaba que Jordi está colgado físicamente de un balcón de verdad.

Comment: Otras veces, para entender una metáfora, uno tiene que entender la cultura. Por ejemplo, para Usted el número 4 no significa nada en especial, pero para un sinohablante este número tiene un significado negativo.

Comment: Dicho esto, agradezco muchísimo a aquellos miembros que me han ayudado a mejorar mi español en este foro todo este tiempo. No tenían por qué ayudarme, pero lo hicieron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué es lo que está "**colgado**" en "colgado del balcón de tus ojos" ?

Lo que esta "**colgado en esta canción es uno mismo**", el cantante expresa una atracción que no puede evitar por esa persona a la que va dedicada la canción.

---

> ...suicida saltando sin red hacía tu corazón, **colgando** del balcón de tus
> ojos de azúcar y miel....

Es una forma poética que utiliza parte de la expresión "**estar colgado por alguien**", es decir estar profundamente enamorado, atraído, enamorado, loco, pillado... por otra persona, a través de la cual se construye la oración y el sentido completo que desea expresar al describir que es lo que le atrae o enamora, utilizando el balcón como metáfora, al ser un lugar abierto por donde penetra la claridad de la luz, el balcón metafóricamente representan los ojos de la casa. En este sentido aprovechando eso dice "de tus ojos de azúcar y miel" otra metáfora, es decir, la traducción paladín sería "**enamorado de la luz de tus ojos dulces y de color meloso** (*color parecido a la miel, marrón muy claro*)... *desesperadamente enamorado*.

**P.D.** También existe la expresión "estar colado por alguien".

En otros contextos "colgado" puede indicar alguien ebrio o alguien loco o drogado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por las explicaciones de los dos. Yo no sabía que "estar colgado por alguien" significa  estar profundamente enamorado.  Pensaba que Jordi está colgado físicamente de un balcón de verdad .

Comment: Gracias a ti, espero que te haya ayudado a comprender un poco mejor los entresijos de esta lengua.

Answer (score 0):

> Jamás imaginé que *yo* pudiera ser *un suicida*:
>
> - *saltando* sin red hacia tu corazón
> - *colgado* del balcón de tus ojos de azúcar y miel.

*Un suicida* en esta oración es atributo del sujeto *yo* y, por lo tanto, se refiere a la misma persona. En otras palabras, el autor es el que está saltando y está colgado.

Temor y fascinación. Jordi siente ambas cosas a la vez. Temor porque está corriendo un riesgo enorme, y fascinación porque no puede evitar enamorarse de esos hermosos ojos.

Para él, la sensación es como la que se vive cuando uno tiene vértigo y se está al borde de un precipicio.

De hecho, para él es peor que eso. Su miedo y su pasión son ambos tan extremos que le parece que estuviera colgado de un balcón, intentando desesperadamente volver a subir a la seguridad del suelo.

Pero un poeta nunca lo diría de una manera tan técnica, por supuesto. Más bien los ojos de la persona amada se convierten en balcón, y en pocas palabras, Jordi ha transmitido tanto su ineludible temor como su pasión.